# How identify all controls in chart when it arranged superimpose?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have developed,Coded UI support for my control(Chart).My Control contains collection of controls.These are arranged on the top of another.
For example,I have add chart area and series (series present top of the area).
When recording, click the chart area but coded ui doesn't identify that control it should give a message for "click series custom control".
So how can I identify each control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is the control you are clicking is probably not exposed to UIA. You said you added UIA support for Chart, but did you add support for the type of your controls in your collection of controls?

Btw, a simple way of seeing if a control can be identified by UIA is using the Inspect tool. You can find the tool under your SDK installation (mine for example is under: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64), or search for msdn inspect.exe to download from MS.